# How to invoke command link/button action anyway regardless of validation error

Tags: validation, jsf-2, action, actionlistener

My command link/button is not being invoked because of a validation error. However, even if I have that error I want my action to be invoked anyway, because I have to set some value in session.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to add `immediate="true"` to your `h:commandLink`. This will skip validation when clicking the link.

See [this link](http://www.javabeat.net/qna/497-what-is-the-use-of-immediate-attribute/) or the [walkthrough](http://balusc.blogspot.de/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html) from BalusC for more information.

Note that your model will not be updated when the action is called, so you wont have access to *any* of the values the user entered.

Comment: No I already have immediate="true" on my commandLink, the problem here is that action is not being invoked because I have validation error